# Whats the best way to do widget animations on Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation

I created an Android app which also animates its widget for about a minute while its running (similar to the airplane mode switch on HTC phones). For the animation, I used remote views and a background thread which changes the widgets imageViews about every 500ms.

The code is similar to this one:

```
appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.widgetGraphics);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class), view);
```

(The animation is a simple frame animation with about 5 images, on repeat.)

This solution works quite alright, feels a bit of a hack though. Is there any better way out there to animate widgets? (Its OK if it works only after version 2.3.3.)

Answer (score 0):

App widgets are not meant to be animated. Most likely, the "airplane mode switch on HTC phones" is not an app widget, but rather a feature of their home screen.

Comment: HTC: are you sure? You can install it from the "add widget" menu...(I've read tons of articles on widgets, and apparently every animation costs lots of battery - and therefore my one will be easy to switch on/off -, but still, i think its a nice feature.)

Comment: @Wimagguc: "You can install it from the "add widget" menu" -- I can put a menu in any application that has a label of "add widget", and none of them will involve app widgets. Those are simply two English words. Home screen makers often blend widget-esque built-in features with actual third-party app widgets. For a short while, HTC had them separated as "HTC Widgets" and "Android Widgets", but dropped that, probably out of user confusion. Now, if you install a third-party home screen replacement, and *it* shows the HTC airplane mode switch, *then* you know it really is an app widget.